# Material UI - Invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When I add a mui element to a component, I start getting the `Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call.` error even when I don't use any hooks.

I have spent way too many hours trying to find a solution but nothing has worked.
I appreciate any help.

NOTE: The error occurs whenever I use a MUI element (any element, not just the modal), regardless of where I use them.

***The Error***
[image]

***The Code (used a hardcoded boolean instead of the hook, the error still continues)***

```
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
    <Card className="project-card-view">
      <Card.Body>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleOpen} > </Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>

    <Modal
  open={true}
  onClose={handleClose}
  aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
  aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
>
  
  <Box>
    <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
      Text in a modal
    </Typography>
    <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
      Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
    </Typography>
  </Box>
</Modal>

  </>
```

***The imports of the component***

```
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

import React from "react";
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4"
  }
```

Comment: have you added the imports for the material UI components inside your component?

Comment: @Amryasser Of course, edited the question to add them, please check it again.

Comment: I copied your code. I didn't find the issue. instead, things working good :D. that's weird. I just added the open state to the model because it was opened at the first. when I click on the button it appears. [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-lumiere-y8tiih?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: I notice that you have @mui/material (v5) and @material-ui/core (v4).  These versions may be colliding.   You are using version 5 within your component.  I would suggest removing the @material-ui/core": "^4.12.4 dependency.  You also may need to install the emotion libraries per https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/.

Comment: @Amryasser I know, my colleague has tried it and it worked on his computer as well, we suspect it might be a different part of the application. I discovered that the error happens whenever I use a mui element regardless of where I put them.

Comment: @ckesplin Didn't work, still getting the same error.

Comment: @DeveloperKurt check the [docs](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html). it's related to the version of **React-dom** for the warning.